# The number of Feats and Talents gained each level seems excessive. Is my reading right?

Tags: feats, character-advancement, exodus-rpg

I'm using Exodus to start up a new post apocalyptic campaign but I'm not sure if I'm reading the advancement rules right.

A character gains a Feat and Talent at level 1, then a Feat every level that is divisible by 3 while Talents are awarded every level divisible by 5.  Then in the Class Skill section (picking aggressive or defensive skill) the PC gets an extra Talent at level 1, Bonus Feat and level 2, they go back and forth (up to level 10).

This seems like a *lot* of Feats and Talents the characters acquire, especially at the beginning. I've done the math and the characters will **always** obtain something at each level, and in some cases will double up on a Talent or a Feat selection.

My question is this: **Am I reading and understanding this right?**

Comment: Hey Seven, thanks for making it a bit clearer... and less verbose ha ha

Answer (score 5):

(I'm going to assume that you have some background with D&D 3.5, which uses the same D20 system that Exodus does.)

Yes, you are reading it correctly. When creating a character, or leveling one up, the character receives Feats/Talents listed on page 22 as per their class AND the Feats/Talents/Ability Increases listed on page 24. Because of this, "dead" levels where you don't get a Feat/Talent are rare, but they can still come up.

When you combine the Class and Level Feats with the Feats that can be gained from your Background and Occupation, you are absolutely correct about it being extremely "front-loaded". It's not uncommon to start off with around six or more feats. For example, the Survivalist background gives the following feats: Simple Weapon Proficiency, Archaic Weapon Proficiency, Personal Firearms Proficiency, Light Armor Proficiency and the choice of Guide or Track. That's five Feats right there!

Part of the reason for this front loading is because the Aggressive/Defensive classes are completely different than standard D&D classes. Standard D&D classes also give out Weapon and Armor Proficencies, while Exodus' Aggressive and Defensive classes don't. There are also more different types of Weapon Proficiencies in Exodus than in D&D 3.5

When compared to another D20 system, this can seem like a LOT. But Exodus has a large number of Feat and Talent trees. Because of those, you actually end up having to spend more Feats/Talents to get what you actually want. (A "feat tax", if you will.)

Source: I have played one full Exodus campaign as a player, and we are currently close to wrapping up a second full campaign. I've made three different characters using the system and helped other players level up their characters as well.

Comment: Thanks... this is exactly what I was thinking and wondering.  I've played D&D YEARS ago, but more recently attempted my hand at being a GM in a Pathfinder campaign.  I see the similarities between Barbarian or Rogue obtaining their feats at specific levels, as well as the standard revolutions of feats depending upon their level.